# How to print out individual digits of an integer in reverse order c++

Tags: c++, integer, user-input, reverse

I have an assignment that instructs:

> Write a function called PrintDigits that takes in a single integer and prints out the individual digits of that integer in reverse order (1s digit first, then 10s digit, then 100s digit and so on), one per line, and returns the number of digits printed. This should work for positive or negative integers
>   Then write a main function that asks the user for 2 integers, prints out the digits of those two integers (using the PrintDigits function that you wrote), and tells the user which integer has the most digits and what the difference in digits is. You may assume the user input is two integers.

But my problem is if I should use an array or not. I know that with arrays you can single out individual digits and print them in reverse order but I'm not sure if this would work for breaking down an individual integer. I've tried using an array but I dont think this is the right route to go anymore. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void PrintDigits(int[], int);

int main()
{    
    int int1[8], int2[8];

    cout << "Please input two integers: ";
    cin >> int1[8] >> int2[8];

    cout << "\n\nDigits of " << int1[8];
    cout << PrintDigits(int1, 8);



    return 0;
}

void PrintDigits (int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << '/n';
}
```

Is there an alternative way to get these results without an array?

Comment: Division and a loop is all you need..

Comment: I don't understand the arrays. Are you sure that's what you wanted to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array, but you don't have to. This question is a classic introductory exercise to recursion.

**NEEDLESS TO SAY YOU COULD CHOOSE TO USE A LOOP INSTEAD OF THE RECURSION BUT I THINK RECURSION IS ELEGANT**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int val) {
    int new_val = val / 10;
    int dig = val % 10;
    cout << dig << " ";
    if (new_val > 0) {
        func(new_val);
    }
}

int main() {
    func(4321);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Explanation

Extract the rightmost digit with the `%` operator. Print it. If the number represented by the other digits is greater than 0, repeat the process.

This outputs: `1 2 3 4`

Comment: Why give the answer?  This question is the classic beginners question.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, I'm not sure I understand, why not give the answer?

Comment: This technically isn't the complete solution to the OP's homework question :), the question requires you to print them on a separate line and account for negative numbers, I've just provided them with 1 possible way to extract digits :)

Comment: Because it is a question designed for the beginner student.  Reversing an integer is given as an assignment as a rite of passage in the world of programming.

Comment: Well, I won't comment on that :), if students are conscientious they won't copy and do it themselves. But there is no harm in elucidating the concept right :D ?

Comment: @Srini if I need to change it to a while loop, would the condition still be the same? I want to count each digit so it prints as: Digit 1: 4, Digit 2: 3, etc, but I want to add a counter so that the digit will count what number its on but when I add a for loop it doesnt display it correctly and prints twice

Comment: I tried adding:                                                                                       void PrintDigits (int val)
{
    int new_val = val / 10;
    int dig = val % 10;
    for (int i=1; i < dig; i++)
        cout << "Digit " << i << ": " << dig << endl;
        if (new_val > 0) {
        PrintDigits(new_val);
    }
}

Comment: Hi @HollyThorsted, in the future, edit the question or post a new question :), it's difficult to read multiline code in the comments. I wanted to edit the answer as per your requirements. But since you already accepted the answer, I've posted the code [here](https://pastebin.com/WkyzwBDy).

Comment: @Srini wow thank you so much, I've been struggling playing around with it trying to not make it be a never ending loop. You're awesome

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is using a `string`. Then you can just read in a string which happens to be all numbers, then output it in reverse order:

```
std::string reverse;
for(size_t i = (line.size() - 1); i >= 0; --i)
{
    reverse += line[i];
}
```

As long as `line` is a string or a `char*`, you can do this, you just have to use a `string` instead of an `int`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int const number = ::rand();

    for (int iterator = number; number; number /= 10)
    ::printf("[%i]", number % 10);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This usually works for me. If you’re looking to convert the number to a string change `number % 10` to `"0123456789"[number % 10]` or `'0' + (number % 10)`.

Mind you, it’s still all in reverse.